# How can I give it a row and column?

Tags: pandas

```
a = df.groupby('actor_1_name')['gross'].sum()
b = df.groupby('actor_2_name')['gross'].sum()
c = df.groupby('actor_3_name')['gross'].sum()
x = pd.concat([a,b,c]).nlargest(3)
x
```

The output for this code is^
[image]

How can I make it look like this:

[image]

Jezrael's new output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `DataFrame` from `Series` - `index` create new column:

```
x = pd.concat([a,b,c]).nlargest(3).rename_axis('name').reset_index()
```

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series([3.71,3.39,3.26],index=['Johny Depp','Harrison Ford','tom Hanks'],name='gross')
print (s)
Johny Depp       3.71
Harrison Ford    3.39
tom Hanks        3.26
Name: gross, dtype: float64

df = s.rename_axis('name').reset_index()
print (df)
            name  gross
0     Johny Depp   3.71
1  Harrison Ford   3.39
2      tom Hanks   3.26
```

---

```
df = s.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'name'})
print (df)
            name  gross
0     Johny Depp   3.71
1  Harrison Ford   3.39
2      tom Hanks   3.26
```

Comment: how can I change 'index' to another name?

Comment: I add 2 possible solutions.